# What is the packet data path for loopback traffic when using a physical interface's address?

Tags: networking

I have an application that transmits hours and hours of web sockets traffic at 40gbps+ between two processes on the same system. The serving-end is bound to an IP address of a physical interface on the system. After a few hours, the receiving end fails to respond to a SYN for long enough to cause the web socket to close.

What is the packet flow when traffic is local like this. Does it touch the physical NIC driver does traffic hairpin the loopback interface (even though it's not addressed to it, but still local?).

Does this traffic hit queues, bpf, iptables?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, all local traffic goes through the `lo` interface, and doesn't touch the physical interface, no matter which locally assigned IP address is used. You can test this with `ip route get 1.2.3.4`, where `1.2.3.4` is the local address, it should show `dev lo`.

I would assume the normal kernel bpf and iptables path for `lo` applies, but I haven't verified this myself. That's again easy to test (and you can do that yourself): Make the appropriate iptables rules or bpf program, and see if it gets hit.